# ModelState is always considered valid, regardless of null values in required fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, modelstate

[I've been](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240834/model-validation-why-modelstate-isvalid-always-returns-true-even-when-no-value) [looking](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api) [around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686690/handle-modelstate-validation-in-asp-net-web-api) and I think my solution is just fine but somehow the `ModelState.IsValid` property is always `true`.

Consider the following code snippets:

```
[Route("address")]
[HttpPut]
[ResponseType(typeof(UserViewModel))]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateAddress([FromBody] UpdateAdressValidationModel model)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       return BadRequest(ModelState);
   }
   // irrelevant code omitted
}

[TestMethod]
public void UpdateAddress_WithoutStreet_ReturnsHttpCode400()
{
    var userController = new UserController(new UserRepository(_context));
    var addressInfo = new UpdateAdressValidationModel
    {
        City = "Ghent",
    };

    var response = userController.UpdateAddress(addressInfo) as BadRequestResult;

    Assert.IsNotNull(response);
}

public class UpdateAdressValidationModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Street { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int? Number { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Bus { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int? PostalCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Still gives me a valid modelstate, even though it clearly shows that the required properties are `null`.

[image]

What am I overlooking?

Note that [manually adding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165026/testing-modelstate-is-always-valid-in-asp-net-mvc?rq=1)

```
Validator.ValidateObject(model, new ValidationContext(model));
```

at the top of the `UpdateAddress` method throws a `ValidationException` on the `Street` field so it can in fact validate the model. Question remains: why doesn't it automatically?

Furthermore, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923622/modelstate-isvalid-even-when-it-should-not-be) isn't applicable because my `model` isn't `null`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Testing ModelState is always valid in asp.net mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165026/testing-modelstate-is-always-valid-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165026/testing-modelstate-is-always-valid-in-asp-net-mvc/8165243#8165243) had the right idea but the solution didn't quite fit.

> Validation happens when the posted data is bound to the view model. The view model is then passed into the controller. You are skipping part 1 and passing a view model straight into a controller.

Which is correct, but the proposed solution throws a ValidationException instead of simply setting the `IsValid` property to `false`.

Luckily, there is a specific method that can do this: [`ApiController.Validate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.validate(v=vs.118).aspx). By adding these lines to my Unit Test it sets the `ModelState` to invalid and *does not throw an exception*.

```
userController.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
userController.Validate(addressInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in your execution path causes validation to occur.  That's done as part of the model binding, which you aren't doing as you're manually creating your model instance.